# Tracking API for iOS devices

Tags: ios, flurry, testflight

Can I track how often people use my app or game on iOS device, as far as I know Apple does not provide any features for this.

Maybe I can use thrid API if it exist.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend the two options that I know of: [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) and the [TestFlight SDK - more specifically the Checkpoint API](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/download/).

Comment: ok, thanks! I need to integrate this SDK into my app? correct?

Comment: Exactly.  My personal preference is to use Flurry over TestFlight, but I'd suggest you read the documentation on both to see which one fits better your needs.

Comment: sorry one question. can I add TestFlight for track user click when app already on app store?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Right, Apple will only tell you downloads.

Flurry analytics is pretty good. http://flurry.com

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) for sure. Always worked like a charm for me.